# MS Access VBA .recordcount returning 0 when records exist, and debug.print returns value

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

I have an Access table with 10 records and one field of short text. I am using the .recordcount function to return the number of records in this table. Code below:

```
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim RS as DAO.Recordset
Dim recCount as Integer
Set db = CurrentDb
Set RS = db.OpenRecordset("Table Name")

RS.MoveFirst
RS.MoveLast
recCount = RS.recordcount

Debug.Print(recCount)

Dim i as Integer
i = 0
RS.MoveFirst
'Option one. Commented out when option two is active and vice verse
Do While i < 10
    Debug.Print(RS(i))
    i = i + 1
Loop

Do While i < 10
    Debug.print(RS![Only Field Name])
    i = i + 1
    RS.MoveNext
Loop
```

recCount always prints out to be 0. Attempting to print out the records in the recordset will return the first value only of the recordset and nothing else. After reading the first record, the program throws the error "Item not found in collection." I'm unsure of what could be causing this error, as I use the exact same method with another table in another VBA module, which works just fine.

I look at solutions to this elsewhere and the only one I could find was to add a `RS.moveFirst` and `RS.moveLast` after opening, however this does not work. I think this is becuase the opened recordset does not actually contain all the records in the table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an endless loop since `i` is never incremented. You need to move to the last record in order to get the recordcount on a DAO recordset.

Comment: @KostasK. Sorry, I have i incremented in my real code. Just threw this together as a quick example to remove unrelated code and shorten variable names and forgot to add that part. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue but I have no idea why this worked. Instead of creating a new table and typing in the values for the ten records, I instead used an insert query to put the values I wanted from a query into a table. Using this new table, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT:

Try this:

```
Sub Demo_IterateRecords()
    Const tblName = "YOUR TABLE NAME HERE"
    Dim rs As Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(tblName)
    With rs
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst

        If MsgBox("Do you want to list all " & .RecordCount & " records?", _
            vbOKCancel, "Confirmation") <> vbOK Then GoTo ExitMySub

        Do While Not .EOF
            Debug.Print .Fields(0), .Fields(1), .Fields(2)
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop

ExitMySub:
        .Close
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

I used `.Fields(_)` because I'm not sure what your fields are called, but a better way to refer to them would be by name, like:

```
        Debug.Print !myID, !myEmployeeName, !myEmployeeAddress
```

---

### Original Answer:

Try this:

```
RS.MoveLast
RS.MoveFirst
recCount = RS.RecordCount
Debug.Print(recCount)
```

Access doesn't know how many records there are until you move through them at least once.

If you would have checked the value of `RS.RecordCount` *after* your loop, you would have got a number.

> ### Remarks
>
> Use the `Recordcount` property to find out how many records in a Recordset or `TableDef` object have been accessed. The `RecordCount` property doesn't indicate how many records are contained in a dynaset–, snapshot–, or forward–only–type Recordset object until all records have been accessed. Once the last record has been accessed, the `RecordCount` property indicates the total number of undeleted records in the Recordset or TableDef object. To force the last record to be accessed, use the MoveLast method on the Recordset object. You can also use an SQL `Count` function to determine the approximate number of records your query will return.
>
> ## Important Note
>
> Using the `MoveLast` method to populate a newly opened Recordset negatively impacts performance. **Unless it is necessary to have an accurate `RecordCount` as soon as you open a Recordset**, it's better to **wait until you populate the Recordset with other portions of code** before checking the `RecordCount` property.

<sup>([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff821452.asp))</sup>

---

See also: **MSDN : [Recordset.RecordCount Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff821452.asp)**

Comment: Please refer back to my question. I attempted this already and it did not work.

Comment: I have tired to put the movefirst/movelast functions after opening the recordset but before calling the .recordcount function, as you have suggested. It still does not work. Even if I move my debug.print statement around, I have a lopp that relies on the result of the recordcount that does not happend becuase the result is still 0 regardless.

Comment: Additionally, the loop with the debug.print statement inside is just to try to print out all the values in the recordset. It will still print just the first then throw an error regardless of if I have movefirst/movelast calls as you recommended

Comment: @jpc  Can you share the code where you tried that? I suspect I know the issue. Also, what about after you retrieve the records?

Comment: I edited the original code to be what I tired with the movefirst/movelast calls. Again though, this unfortunately did not work. I even tried moving those statements to other locations to see if anything worked but to no avail.

Comment: @jpc I edited my solution - make sure you have the one with the `RecordCount` property...  slight oversight on the earlier draft :)

Comment: Thanks! I tried your solutions with the added edit, and it printed out the first and second record values! Although there are 10, I guess the first two is better than the first one so that is progress, but also makes it a bit more odd...

Answer (score 1):

You could list the records while counting:

```
Set RS = db.OpenRecordset("Table Name")

While Not RS.EOF
    Debug.Print RS![Only Field Name].Value
    i = i + 1
    RS.MoveNext
Loop

Debug.Print i & " records found."
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try something similar to this in your sub routine:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Dim recCount As Integer
Set db = CurrentDb
Set RS = db.OpenRecordset("Table Name")
If Not (RS.EOF And RS.BOF) Then
RS.MoveFirst
Do Until RS.EOF = True
RS.MoveNext
Loop
MsgBox ("There are:" & " " & RS.RecordCount & " " & "records in the database")
End If
RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
```